# Add 2 number without sign extension

Tags: algorithm, addition

Do we have any algorithm to add or sub 2 different binary number(with different size) , without sign extension?

for example 
-3 is 1111101 and
1024 is 10000000000
how can I add these numbers without sign extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all. That's just part of the basic arithmetic rules for 2s complement numbers. Adding numbers without sign-extension will cause an incorrect result for most numbers of different length.

And just a little sidenote: 1024 is only 10000000000 in **unsigned** binary code. in 2s complement, it'd be stored as 010000000000 (note the sign-bit set to 0).